# how to highlight stack bar in ChartJS with onclick

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to select a column in a stack bar chart with a colored border? Like this

[image]

I started from here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sdfx/hwx9awgn/

```js
// Return with commas in between   
var numberWithCommas = function(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};
var dataPack1 = [40, 47, 44, 38, 27, 31, 25];
var dataPack2 = [10, 12, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8];
var dataPack3 = [17, 11, 22, 18, 12, 7, 5];
var dates = ["SN 1.0.1", "SN 1.0.2", "SN 1.0.3", "SN 1.0.4", "SN 1.0.5", "SN 2.0.0", "SN 2.0.1"];
// Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';  
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart');
var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Bad Style',
          data: dataPack1,
          backgroundColor: "#512DA8",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "#7E57C2",
          hoverBorderWidth: 0
        }, {
          label: 'Warning',
          data: dataPack2,
          backgroundColor: "#FFA000",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "#FFCA28",
          hoverBorderWidth: 0
        }, {
          label: 'Error',
          data: dataPack3,
          backgroundColor: "#D32F2F",
          hoverBackgroundColor: "#EF5350",
          hoverBorderWidth: 0
        }, ]
      },
      options: {
        animation: {
          duration: 10,
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'label',
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            gridLines: {
              display: false
            },
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value) {
                return numberWithCommas(value);
              },
            },
          }],
        }, // scales         legend: {display: true}     } // options    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you can do is in the onClick as second argument you get an array with all the active elements. So what you can do is loop over each dataset in your chart and see if the index matches one of the list with active elements.

If this is the case you give it a `borderWidth` of 1, else you put it to 0. After you did this you call chart variable.update();

To make this work you need to remove the hoverBorderWidth of all datasets and give all datasets a `borderColor` of yellow

Comment: Thanks for reply... I add this function on onclick: onClick: function (e, items) {
    this.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, index) => {
        console.log(dataset.backgroundColor, index);
        dataset.borderColor = "yellow";
    });
but select all stack bar :(

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute borderColor with an array and borderWith with and object.

```
datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Bad Style',
            data: dataPack1,
            backgroundColor: "#512DA8",
            borderColor: [
              'rgb(243, 255, 51)',
              'rgb(81,45,168)',
              'rgb(243, 255, 51)',
              'rgb(81,45,168)',
              'rgb(81,45,168)',
              'rgb(81,45,168)',
              'rgb(81,45,168)',
            ],
            borderWidth: {
               top: 0,
               right: 4,
               bottom: 0,
               left: 4
            },
        },
```

rgb(243, 255, 51) is yellow color.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color, try this:

```
var borderColor =  [
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
   'rgb(81,45,168)',
];
var bar_ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart');
var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Bad Style',
            data: dataPack1,
            backgroundColor: "#512DA8",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "#7E57C2",
            hoverBorderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: borderColor,
            borderWidth: '4',
        },
        {
            label: 'Warning',
            data: dataPack2,
            backgroundColor: "#FFA000",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "#FFCA28",
            hoverBorderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: borderColor,
            borderWidth: '4',
        },
        {
            label: 'Error',
            data: dataPack3,
            backgroundColor: "#D32F2F",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "#EF5350",
            hoverBorderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: borderColor,
            borderWidth: '4',
        },
        ]
    },
    options: {
            onClick: function(e){
               var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
               borderColor[element[0]._index] = 'rgb(244,140,4)';
               this.update();
        },
            animation: {
               duration: 10,
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'label',
          callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) { 
            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
          }
          }
         },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{ 
            stacked: true, 
            gridLines: { display: false },
            }],
          yAxes: [{ 
            stacked: true, 
            ticks: {
                    callback: function(value) { return numberWithCommas(value); },
                    }, 
            }],
        }, // scales
        legend: {display: true}
    } // options
   }
);
```